# jquery .append failure with html tags

Tags: jquery, html

iam using firefox 51.01 and chrome 56.0.2924.87 (newest versions on windows 10), when i try using .append with jquery 2.2.3 the html tags in the var data will be deleted, on another website with jquery 1.9.1 it will work, here is my code

```
<div id="results"></div>

<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
data = "<tr><td>333</td><td>John</td><td>11-7-2014</td></tr>";
$("#results").append(data);
})
</script>
```

has anyone an idea ? i tried also .html, but the same

Comment: Wrap it in document ready function. like `$(document).ready(function(){ })`

Comment: And the javascript isnt in `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put JavaScript inside a `<script>` tag, or load it from an external .js file.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results"></table>

<script>data = "<tr><td>333</td><td>John</td><td>11-7-2014</td></tr>";
$("#results").append(data);</script>
```

Also, your `#results` should be a table, not a div, if you want to add table rows to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a complete running example to help you.

I'm using the same version of jQuery as you (v 2.2.3). Also the same Chrome and OS version (Windows 10).

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var data = "<tr><td>333</td><td>John</td><td>11-7-2014</td></tr>";
    $("#results").append(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: i cant use the table tag because its double than, can i use a neutral tag inside a table ?